# Scalar mechanics

Tags: classical-mechanics

Can someone please suggest me some books which treat and teach Newtonian Mechanics ( Statics and Dynamics ) without the use of vectors? I was wondering how can we carry out the same treatments with a scalar based method like it was done before the adoption of vector methods.

Comment: You can look at Chandrasekhar's expose [Newton's Principia for the Common Reader](https://www.amazon.com/Newtons-Principia-Common-Reader-Physics/dp/0198517440). A number of older textbooks that came before the time of vectors is listed under [What would have been the popular textbook to learn mechanics in the 19 th century?](http://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/3623/what-would-have-been-the-popular-textbook-to-learn-mechanics-in-the-19-th-centur)

Comment: Newton's Principia also does not use Calculus. Books that use Calculus but not vectors just write every vector equation as 3 scalar equations. Most 19 century books and some of the 20th century books are written like this. There is really no much difference.

Comment: Maxwell's equations were originally 20 in number, not 4, because they were written in component form, not vector form.  Don't expect that writing out all equations in terms of scalar components is really simpler. There is, after all, a reason vector methods were adopted.

Comment: The components of a vector are not scalars. A scalar is a quantity that doesn't change under rotation.

Comment: @BenCrowell I understand what you are getting at, but I think it is fair in this question to regard the OP's use of the term "scalar" as meaning a synonym for "number" in the elementary sense rather than the physicist's more strict meaning of "scalar". After all, how are we otherwise supposed to interpret the OP writing that before vector methods were developed, Newtonian mechanics was treated by a scalar-based method?